# To what extent can someone be punished by a public institution without a rule or law being clearly stated?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, canada, punishment

Say a patient does something the director of the hospital thinks is inappropriate. Or say it is a student and a school instead of a patient and a hospital. The important point is that a "user" of a "service" is punished without reference to a rule or a law. Is it allowed? I am especially interested in the law in Canada, but also in the United States and the UK.

Comment: You need to further define "user" and "service" and "punish" and what basis - the law, a policy, etc. - the authorities are referring to.

Comment: Let us assume that the user is a patient and the service is a hospital, as in the first example. Say the punishment is the patient being forbidden to use the hospital. The problem is precisely the lack of a clear basis.

Comment: "patient being forbidden to use the hospital." How so "forbidden"? Refuse treatment? Public or private hospital? What law or policy do they cite to "forbid" use?

Comment: Being refused service when demonstrating inappropriate behaviour isn't a punishment any more than not being allowed a driver's license for not showing you can drive is.

Comment: As written this is too vague to be answered. You need to give more detail. "Inappropriate" could cover a huge range of behaviour, some of which would endanger other patients, or dissuade them from seeking treatment, Hospital staff also have legitimate concerns about harm. All these would have to be considered by hospital administrators. Likewise for schools. Also, different laws govern schools and hospitals. Do you have a specific example?

Comment: I want to be vague to focus in what I want, which is discussing the legality of punishing someone WITHOUT reference to any written law of any sort.

Comment: I am writing a sequence of more specific questions to see if I can get the answer I am looking for, see https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/52427/can-the-manager-of-a-commercial-establishment-forbid-someone-to-enter and https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/52432/in-a-public-university-can-the-head-of-department-forbid-a-specific-student-to.