# Can the manager of a commercial establishment forbid someone to enter?

Tags: canada

Suppose that the manager uses as an argument something as vague as "I didn't like what you did here last week" and does not cite any law nor policy.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. The person having control other the establishment can disallow you to enter unless the reason is illegal discrimination. They don’t need to cite any law, “I don’t want you in here” is enough reason. No explanation needed *why* and if they give an explanation, “I don’t like your face” is enough.

Comment: Do you have any source to support your answer?

Comment: @Seno the specific statute depends on the province, but they're mostly similar everywhere - here's Ontario Trespass to Property Act https://www.ontario.ca/laws/statute/90t21 - you are on private property, and if you " does not leave the premises immediately after he or she is directed to do so by the occupier of the premises or a person authorized by the occupier," then you would be guilty of trespass.

Comment: @Peteris, so you are stating that a supermarket would be bound to the same law as a house?

Comment: Or, maybe in a more compelling case, a medical clinic would be bound to the same law as a house?

Comment: @Seno yes, almost. From the perspective of property rights there's no difference between the building you sleep in and the building where you work, in both cases you have the right to determine who is allowed to enter and who is not. The main difference is in the implied permission, i.e. a shop or medical clinic with open doors during its normal working hours is not prohibiting entry to anyone - but as soon as the responsible manager gives you notice that you're not welcome there, *you* are prohibited from staying in *the exact same manner* as they would be prohibited to stay in your bedroom.

Comment: @Seno going on with the medical clinic example - in a medical clinic, a door with a red sign "AUTHORIZED PERSONELL ONLY" is one way how the owner or their representative could legally prohibit entry to everyone who's not explicitly authorized, and an oral notice personally to you "you're forbidden to enter" is an equivalent prohibition that explicitly applies to you; in both cases the violator would be guilty of the offence of trespass. Of course, specific laws may also apply in various conditions - e.g. non-discrimination for shops, medical clinics can plausibly also have extra rules.

Comment: I think it is appropriate to ask a different question for this regard, but what if the place is not privately owned? For the sake of argument, what if the place is a government bureau, a park or a public university.

Comment: Gotta be careful with the "I don't like your face" reason.